# Bind url, uri parameter to url at run time

Tags: java, spring, url

I am using spring boot. I have the following url.

`url` = `example.com/api/{modelId}/log?name={cat}`

`URI uri` = `URI.create(url);`

I want to bind `modelId` and `name` at run time?

How can I achieve this?
Thanks..!

Comment: How about [reading](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) the official reference [first](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)?

Comment: @MarcTarin thanks for ur reply.

I know how to extract parameters from a url. What I am trying to do is , I want to bind parameters to a url  at run time, so that after binding parameters to url I can make a rest post call using spring template

Comment: @MarcTarin you mean something like this : `UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(
        "http://example.com/hotels/{hotel}/bookings/{booking}").build();

URI uri = uriComponents.expand("42", "21").encode().toUri();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **spring boot**(`org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate;`) template

```
        String url = "www.google.com/{name}/{mobile}";
        UriTemplate template = new UriTemplate(url);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name", "#PCP");
        map.put("mobile", "123456789");
        URI uri = template.expand(map);
        System.out.println("uri=" + uri.getPath());
```

**Output** :

```
uri=www.google.com/#PCP/123456789
```

Comment: You can also use `@PathVariable` annotation. I hope you are doing this in a controller!